# Blender locks up if I minimise it

Tags: windows

I run blender on a three monitor computer.  I'm new to blender and 3D modelling though I have played in Unity and other places for a while.

I have created a startup file that opens a blender window for each monitor and distributed various parts of the views so I can see the whole model build.  Every now and again I want to look at other information and minimise blender.  If I do that, blender will never restore the window.  It will just be waiting for ever and thus I have to kill blender and start again.

This seems a real basic so I doubt many people are suffering this or there would be lots of Solutions/Moans on the net.  Anybody got any idea what is going wrong here?

I'm using Windows 10 on Rhyzen.  I've 32GB Ram to play with and a middling AMD graphics card.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, either in Blender or your graphics driver. I use a multi monitor setup for years without issues try updating graphics drivers

Comment: Many thanks.  I did try that and I did check windows update too.  Currently just trying to remember never to minimise it ;-)